# Unexpected output of a Prolog script

Tags: prolog

```
leftHand(empty).
rightHand(empty).

inHands :-
    write("Left hand:"),
    nl,
    leftHand(X),
    tab(2),
    write(X),
    nl,
    nl,
    write("Right hand:"),
    rightHand(Y),
    tab(2),
    write(Y),
    nl.
```

I expect `inHands.` to return something like this:

```
Left hand:
  empty

Right hand:
  empty
```

However, this is what I saw:

```
 24 ?- inHands.
[76, 101, 102, 116, 32, 104, 97, 110, 100, 58]
  empty

[82, 105, 103, 104, 116, 32, 104, 97, 110, 100, 58]  empty
true.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have to use single quotes like this:

```
write('My text').
```